# C# Next Day of Week Logic

Tags: c#

I am having some issues making this code more efficient; I am writing a basic scheduler and want to know the number of days between the next run from the current day. What I have works, but it seems huge for a simple task?

I set the days of the week I would like using bools in a class...

This is what I have:

```
class Schedule
{
    public string StartTime;
    public bool Monday;
    public bool Tuesday;
    public bool Wednesday;
    public bool Thursday;
    public bool Friday;
    public bool Saturday;
    public bool Sunday;
} 

Schedule jobSchedule = new Schedule();

jobSchedule.Monday = true;
jobSchedule.Tuesday = true;
jobSchedule.Wednesday = false;
jobSchedule.Thursday = true;
jobSchedule.Friday = true;
jobSchedule.Saturday = true;
jobSchedule.Sunday = true;
```

This sets up when I would like the code to run. What I would like now is a function to return an int of the number of days to the next execution... I have the following:

```
   private int nextDay()
    {
        int days = 0;
        DayOfWeek dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

        switch (dow)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                if (jobSchedule.Tuesday) {
                    days += 1;
                } else if (jobSchedule.Wednesday) {
                    days += 2;
                } else if (jobSchedule.Thursday) {
                    days += 3;
                } else if (jobSchedule.Friday) {
                    days += 4;
                } else if (jobSchedule.Saturday) { 
                    days += 5;
                } else if (jobSchedule.Sunday) {
                    days += 6;
                }
        break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                if (jobSchedule.Wednesday)
                {
                    days += 1;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Thursday)
                {
                    days += 2;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Friday)
                {
                    days += 3;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Saturday)
                {
                    days += 4;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Sunday)
                {
                    days += 5;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Monday)
                {
                    days += 6;
                }
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                if (jobSchedule.Thursday)
                {
                    days += 1;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Friday)
                {
                    days += 2;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Saturday)
                {
                    days += 3;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Sunday)
                {
                    days += 4;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Monday)
                {
                    days += 5;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Tuesday)
                {
                    days += 6;
                }
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                if (jobSchedule.Friday)
                {
                    days += 1;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Saturday)
                {
                    days += 2;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Sunday)
                {
                    days += 3;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Monday)
                {
                    days += 4;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Tuesday)
                {
                    days += 5;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Wednesday)
                {
                    days += 6;
                }
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                if (jobSchedule.Saturday)
                {
                    days += 1;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Sunday)
                {
                    days += 2;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Monday)
                {
                    days += 3;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Tuesday)
                {
                    days += 4;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Wednesday)
                {
                    days += 5;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Thursday)
                {
                    days += 6;
                }
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                if (jobSchedule.Sunday)
                {
                    days += 1;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Monday)
                {
                    days += 2;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Tuesday)
                {
                    days += 3;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Wednesday)
                {
                    days += 4;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Thursday)
                {
                    days += 5;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Friday)
                {
                    days += 6;
                }
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                if (jobSchedule.Monday)
                {
                    days += 1;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Tuesday)
                {
                    days += 2;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Wednesday)
                {
                    days += 3;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Thursday)
                {
                    days += 4;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Friday)
                {
                    days += 5;
                }
                else if (jobSchedule.Saturday)
                {
                    days += 6;
                }
                break;
        }

        return days;
    }
```

How could I shorted this down? The above works how I want it but seems too much :(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This seems better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may want to check out [NCrontab](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncrontab), it makes this part of writing a scheduler so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use an `enum` instead of splitting the same logic among `7` variables and a `DateTime` to store your starting time. For what concerns the enumeration, `DayOfWeek` is a good starting point but it doesn't have the `Flags` attribute that allows bit flags operations... so I suggest you to implement your own.

```
[Flags]
public enum ScheduleDays
{
    None = 0x00,
    Monday = 0x01,
    Tuesday = 0x02,
    Wednesday = 0x04,
    Thursday = 0x08,
    Friday = 0x10,
    Saturday = 0x20,
    Sunday = 0x40,
    All = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
}

public class Schedule
{
    public DateTime Start;
    public ScheduleDays Days; // ScheduleDay.None by default
}
```

And this is an usage example:

```
// all days except wednesday
Schedule s = new Schedule();
s.Days = ScheduleDays.All & ~ScheduleDays.Wednesday;
```

In order to calculate the number of days to the next scheduled day I would use the following approach:

```
private static Int32 NextRunDays(ScheduleDays days)
{
    if ((Int32)days == 0)
        return -1;

    ScheduleDays[] values = (ScheduleDays[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ScheduleDays));
    List<Int32> scheduledDays = new List<Int32>(values.Length);

    foreach (ScheduleDays scheduledDay in values)
    {
        Int32 scheduledDayValue = (Int32)scheduledDay;

        if ((scheduledDayValue == 0) || (scheduledDayValue == (Int32)ScheduleDays.All))
            continue;

        if (!days.HasFlag(scheduledDay))
            continue;

        scheduledDays.Add(Array.IndexOf(values, scheduledDay) - 1);
    }

    scheduledDays = scheduledDays.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

    Int32 dowValue = (Int32)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

    if (dowValue == 0)
        dowValue = 6;
    else
        dowValue -= 1;

    List<Int32> scheduledDaysNext = scheduledDays.Where(x => x >= dowValue).ToList();
    Int32 nextDayValue = ((scheduledDaysNext.Count > 0) ? scheduledDaysNext.First() : scheduledDays.First());

    return ((nextDayValue - dowValue + 7) % 7);
}
```

You can try a working example [here](http://rextester.com/ECF62610).

Comment: Interesting approach! I've not used Enums before - This looks like a good manageable way to solve it. However, briefly looking at that code - It returns the Int of the DayOfWeek of the next schedule; instead of how many days until the next schedule. So if today is Monday and Tuesday is in the schedule - it should return 1 (1 day until next Schedule) - or If today is Wednesday and Thu, Fri is not in the schedule but Sat is then it should return 3

Comment: I edited my answer to make it fit your needs. Visit the link to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Well what i would have done is change `Schedule` To hold a `DayOfWeek` instead of all these booleans, but let's say it is not possible, you could do this

```
 private static DayOfWeek ToDayOfWeek(this Schedule schedule, DayOfWeek today)
    {
        while(true)

        {
            if(schedule.Monday && (int)today < (int)DayOfWeek.Monday)
                return DayOfWeek.Monday;
            if(schedule.Tuesday && (int)today < (int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                return DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
            if(schedule.Wednesday&& (int)today < (int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                return DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
            if(schedule.Thursday&& (int)today < (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                return DayOfWeek.Thursday;
            if(schedule.Friday&& (int)today < (int)DayOfWeek.Friday)
                return DayOfWeek.Friday;
            if(schedule.Saturday&& (int)today < (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                return DayOfWeek.Saturday;
            if(schedule.Sunday&& (int)today < (int)DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                return DayOfWeek.Sunday;

            today = (DayOfWeek)(Math.Abs((int)today - 1));
        }
    }

private int DifferenceInDays(DayOfWeek left, DayOfWeek right)
{
     if((left == DayOfWeek.Sunday || right == DayOfWeek.Sunday) && (right == DayOfWeek.Saturday || left == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
     {
        return 1;
     }

     return Math.Abs((int)left - (int)right);
 }


private int nextDay()
{
        int days = 0;
        DayOfWeek dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
       return DifferenceInDays(dow, schedule.ToDayOfWeek(dow));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot change your Schedule class I would consider something like this:

```
    private int NextDay(Schedule jobSchedule)
    {
        var availableSchedules = new[]
        {
            new {Position = 0, Enabled = jobSchedule.Sunday },
            new {Position = 1, Enabled = jobSchedule.Monday },
            new {Position = 2, Enabled = jobSchedule.Tuesday },
            new {Position = 3, Enabled = jobSchedule.Wednesday },
            new {Position = 4, Enabled = jobSchedule.Thursday },
            new {Position = 5, Enabled = jobSchedule.Friday },
            new {Position = 6, Enabled = jobSchedule.Saturday }
        };

        var currentDayOfWeek = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        var currentPosition = currentDayOfWeek + 1;
        var requiredDays = 1;

        //Optional. incase nothing is enabled
        if (!availableSchedules.Any(x => x.Enabled))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(jobSchedule));
        }
        //End Optional. incase nothing is enabled

        do
        {
            var nextSchedule = availableSchedules.First(s => s.Position == currentPosition);

            if (nextSchedule.Enabled)
            {
                break;
            }

            requiredDays++;
            currentPosition++;

            if (currentPosition > 6) //incase we go to the following week. Reset
            {
                currentPosition = 0;
            }

        } while (true);

        return requiredDays;
    }
```

The approach here is to have a scoring mechanism that keeps on incrementing until the next available schedule is found. This works even in cases where the next schedule is in the following week.

If you can change the Schedule class, you could avoid declaring "availableSchedules". I would recommend doing this by adding Position or something similar to your Schedule class